# How to separate routes in Depth First Traversal?

Tags: python

I have two bus routes. I want find the possible paths between a source and a destination. I used Depth First Traversal to find all possible paths. Here are the paths. Here the orange path is the path traveled by bus no.1. The red path is traveled by bus no.2. So a passenger going from 1 to 4 should go from 1 to 3, get down and then take bus no.2.

[image: Routes of Different buses]

Here's what i tried.

```
# Python program to print all paths from a source to destination. 

from collections import defaultdict 

#This class represents a directed graph 
# using adjacency list representation 
class Graph: 

    def __init__(self,vertices): 
        #No. of vertices 
        self.V= vertices 

        # default dictionary to store graph 
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) 

    # function to add an edge to graph 
    def addEdge(self,u,v): 
        self.graph[u].append(v) 

    '''A recursive function to print all paths from 'u' to 'd'. 
    visited[] keeps track of vertices in current path. 
    path[] stores actual vertices and path_index is current 
    index in path[]'''
    def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path): 

        # Mark the current node as visited and store in path 
        visited[u]= True
        path.append(u) 

        # If current vertex is same as destination, then print 
        # current path[] 
        if u ==d: 
            print (path) 
        else: 
            # If current vertex is not destination 
            #Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
            for i in self.graph[u]: 
                if visited[i]==False: 
                    self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path) 

        # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited 
        path.pop() 
        visited[u]= False


    # Prints all paths from 's' to 'd' 
    def printAllPaths(self,s, d): 

        # Mark all the vertices as not visited 
        visited =[False]*(self.V) 

        # Create an array to store paths 
        path = [] 

        # Call the recursive helper function to print all paths 
        self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d,visited, path) 



# Create a graph given in the above diagram 
g = Graph(5) 
g.addEdge(1, 2) 
g.addEdge(2, 3) 
g.addEdge(3, 4)









s = 1 ; d = 4
print ("Following are all different paths from %d to %d :" %(s, d)) 
g.printAllPaths(s, d)
```

***Expected output:***

```
[1,2,3]
[3,4]
```

***Present output:***

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: In path you are only saving whether the you can reach from node A to node B but you want to access another unsaved property `bus-routename` in your case. So you  relationship between node should also have another property like route name to connect them. So a simple edge should store object like `{'destnode': v,'route':'Bus-route-1' }` than mere `v`

Comment: If you don't want to implement all graph related stuff by yourself, you may want to look at ```networkx```. Their you could set edge attributes and reconstruct your output using them.